# How to show multiple basic card as a response in dialogflow webhook

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google, fulfillment

I want to send three basic cards as a response to the user through JSON response via fulfillment in python. So is there any way to do it?

**P.S.**

Basically, I want to show three buttons to a user for `call`, `mail` and `call on office`, but as Basic card shows only one link, I thought is it possible to show multiple cards which contain buttons!

This is the response that I'm sending.

```
{
    "payload": {
        "google": {
            "expectUserResponse": "true",
            "richResponse": {
                "items": [{
                        "simpleResponse": {
                            "textToSpeech": "Here is the information of " + user_name
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "basicCard": {
                            "title": name,
                            "subtitle": subtitle,
                            "image": {
                                "url": picture_url,
                                "accessibilityText": "Picture of " + name
                            },
                            "formattedText": msg,
                            "buttons": [{
                                    "title": "Call " + user_name,
                                    "openUrlAction": {
                                        "url": "tel:+" + contact
                                        if contact is not None
                                        else "",
                                        "androidApp": {
                                            "packageName": "com.android.phone"
                                        },
                                        "versions": []
                                    }
                                }
                                if contact is not None
                                else {
                                    "title": "Send Mail to " + user_name,
                                    "openUrlAction": {
                                        "url": "mailto:" + email,
                                        "androidApp": {
                                            "packageName": "android.intent.extra.EMAIL"
                                        },
                                        "versions": []
                                    }
                                },
                                {
                                    "title": "Call on extention",
                                    "openUrlAction": {
                                        "url": "tel:+" + extension
                                        if extension is not None
                                        else "",
                                        "androidApp": {
                                            "packageName": "com.android.phone"
                                        },
                                        "versions": []
                                    }
                                }

                            ],
                            "imageDisplayOptions": "WHITE"
                        }
                    }
                ],
                "suggestions": [{
                        "title": "Info of " + manager
                        if manager is not None
                        else ""
                    },
                    {
                        "title": "Info of " + hr_manager
                        if hr_manager is not None
                        else ""
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: According to this https://github.com/dialogflow/dialogflow-fulfillment-nodejs/issues/34 there is no support for more than a button. However when I check the documentation here https://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/message-objects#basic_card we see the a table card can have only have 1 button, but it does not specify for the Basic Card - the buttons are of type array (list of external links.)

Comment: Yes, so what are you suggesting?

Answer (score 5):

You can't send multiple cards, and although the buttons on a card take an array, only one element in that array is allowed.

However, you can do something similar by sending a [browsing carousel](https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/responses#browsing_carousel). This lets you send multiple tiles that include a title and may include images, a body, and a link in the same form that a card has a link.

One issue is that I'm not sure if the link is required to be an http or https link, or if other URL forms are allowed, but keep in mind that not all surfaces that may support links support being able to make telephone calls.

Comment: Then what's the point of making buttons as an array if only one element is allowed ??

Comment: My guess is that it was originally designed to support more, but this was changed fairly late in the development process, possibly for UI/UX issues. But that is purely a guess.